# Python: How to create a surface-plot from a collection of 3D coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am given three numpy-arrays, which contain the x, y, and z- coordinates of multiple points, respectively. In fact, there are 100 points, which are arranged in a grid:

[image: grid]

So, although there are 100 points, there are only 10 different x- and 10 different y coordinates. There are, however, 100 different z coordinates.

I thought I could create a surface plot using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def plot_surface():
    x = np.arange(10)
    y = np.arange(10)
    z = z_coords.reshape(10,10)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
```

I am aware that - since I cannot describe the z-coordinate through a function of x and y - the z-coordinate e.g. at x=1 and between y=1 and y=2 will be constant. I am fine with this though.

Anyways, the code doesn't work. Maybe my thinking is wrong. Running this, I get the error:
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: The code works fine if you define `z_coords` and `Z` as you have written in the text. Please consider [mcve]!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure if your z array can be reshaped into (10,10)? I quickly ran the following as I didn't know specifics of your z array, it seems the plotting works as you wanted?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def plot_surface():
    x = np.arange(10)
    y = np.arange(10)
    z = np.zeros((len(x),len(x)))+10
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, z)
plot_surface()
plt.show(True)
```

Comment: yeah. Again, my mistake! It was my x- and y-coordinates. I did not create them with np.arange, but actually had them stored for each of the 100 points. I had to reshape them